# HTML5 Canvas, alter rectangle after it is created

Tags: html, canvas

Is this possible? For example if I have an animation that draws 1 rectangle, and then after 5 seconds it draws a second one, can I target the first one and do something like change its color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll have to do is clear the canvas, draw the 1st rectangle in another color, and then draw the second one.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would be the answer but was hoping there might be a better way.

Comment: You could also draw over the old rect without clearing it first, but besides that this is basically it - You should probably look at SVG if you want something that allows easier manipulation of graphics after they've been drawn. By the way, you should accept echeese's answer if you're satisfied with it... Just in case you don't know the "rules of the land" since you seem to be new :)